# How to save Lucky bamboo yellow stem due to overpruning HELP

Tags: pruning, lucky-bamboo

[image]

Hi, Had this lucky bamboo in a water with stones jar for over 3 years already. I made a terrible mistake of over pruning its babies and regrowing them in another jar. I think I took out 3 pieces out of the course of 1 week. It started turning yellow the week after. Cleaned the water and jar, removed the stone, replaced it in water jar and observed but it seems its not regaining its green color. Yellow going down the stalk. Never had problems in the past years just only when I overpruned them

Question:
 1. How to save the lucky bamboo?
 2. the roots combine with another stem (healthy), shall I separate them?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you mind taking a look at the question referenced as a possible duplicate? It has some answers that might solve your problem. Also, check out our other [lucky-bamboo](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucky-bamboo) questions. If you don't find what you need, feel free to let us know what's missing so we can help you more specifically. Thanks!